# How to sum two values in a list of dictionaries stored in a Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, json

I created this JS variable from a JSON:

```
var myJSON = [
  {
    "": 0,
    "Comune": "BONDENO",
    "PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516": 4.25,
    "Value 1": 63,
    "Value 2": 8,
    "Value 3": 17,
    "DANNO": 6,
    "Somma valori": 88,

  },
  {
    "": 1,
    "Comune": "CAVEZZO",
    "PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516": 3.75,
    "Value 1": 23,
    "Value 2": 2,
    "Value 3": 9,
    "DANNO": 8,
    "Somma valori": 34,

  }, etc.
```

I want to sum Value 1 and Value 2 in each dictionary, so that it would become:

```
sum = [71, 25, etc.]
```

Each of these points would then have to be divided for "DANNO", and the result should be an array because I would have to plot it afterwards. I looked many answers but none answered my doubts.

Comment: Don't look at the problem as a whole - each small part (summing values in an object, mapping/summing an array, etc.) is very specific and definitely have answers here on SO.

Comment: You should take a look at [Array.reduce(..)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: I tried but didn't succeed, that's why I'm asking...

Comment: @Titus i think `.reduce` is an overkill for this, a `.map` should be enough `myJSON.map(e => e["Value 1"] + e["Value 2"]);`

Comment: @Taki actually, yes, now I saw that the result should be an array. [Here is the documentation for Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map(..))

Comment: "I tried but didn't succeed" - right, but part of a good question is providing us with _what you tried_ so we can help point you in the right direction. Saying you searched for answers isn't really enough to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would help to make a function that returns this array by iterating over the objects and performing said operations. Here's a possible solution:

```js
var myJSON = [
  {
    "": 0,
    "Comune": "BONDENO",
    "PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516": 4.25,
    "Value 1": 63,
    "Value 2": 8,
    "Value 3": 17,
    "DANNO": 6,
    "Somma valori": 88,

  },
  {
    "": 1,
    "Comune": "CAVEZZO",
    "PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516": 3.75,
    "Value 1": 23,
    "Value 2": 2,
    "Value 3": 9,
    "DANNO": 8,
    "Somma valori": 34,

  }];
  
const createPlotArray = (data) => {
  let returnArray = data.map(item => 
    (item["Value 1"] + item["Value 2"])/item["DANNO"]
  );
  
  return returnArray;
};

document.querySelector("#root").innerHTML = createPlotArray(myJSON);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: your output does not match what the OP asked for

Comment: It doesn't because OP said they want to also divide the sum by DANNO, which I did. The sum is different after the division. Sorry for the confusion!